# Application Email Architecture

Tags: c#, sql-server, email, architecture

I've inherited an ASP.NET website written in c# using an mssql 2k8 database that is sending emails based on an insert into a message table via a trigger using database mail :|  One of any failures and too many things rollback, aren't logged and no email is sent...

What a mess.  I've written a few email subsystems in the past and I thought I'd ask for input before starting a rewrite here.  What are the best practices for queuing/sending email in a Microsoft environment?  Should I be pushing emails to a queue, from there pulling, sending, logging?  DB Email seems like a fail.  Is the queue managed in SQL server?  Does SQL Server call a C# app?  If an email send fails, what's a good approach for recovery?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: You see an answer here?  I don't, I'll accept one since you've asked.

Comment: @Hottester meant 'in general'.

Comment: @George Stocker I don't know if I just ask "bad questions" or what, but I find my questions turn into tumbleweeds.  I'd love to have more answers.  I'll work on trying to ask more focused and defined questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are correct to completely separate the use of system functions: use SQL for data, and push email on to a completely different 'service provider'; I assume you have some sort of business logic tier that will orchestrate this?

I can't talk in terms of 'best practice' from experience (for email specifically), but abstracting out the email service (just like you'd abstract out data-access) is definitely on the right path, and that's probably the critical decision you need to make right now. You could then have different implementations of the email (including SQL, if you really wanted to).

Depending on volumes - do you look at an asynchronous call or synchronous call? WCF seems like a good candidate to handle comms - this would allow you to fire data (for emails) into an end-point that had a queue built into it, or you could call (via WCF) a web service that acted synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail via sql-server. For more refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

The architecture of it is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189635(SQL.90).aspx)

Another implementation of sending mail via c# is [**this**](http://www.jscape.com/articles/sending_email_using_csharp.html) as they have developed an email factory for implementation... hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I am aware of db mail, in this case, I feel as though it's a fail.  In terms of an overall process with db mail as a component, do you have any other input?

Comment: @Ben - check out the docs for Database Mail, it handles retries etc, you can dig into the db and see the table with the data etc..

PK :-)

Comment: I hear you about retries, but my experience has been email failure = RAISERROR = no retry.  Perhaps my failure is happening at a different point in the db_mail stack.

Answer (score 0):

[sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) places the mail request into a queue in msdb. After the transaction that sent the mail commits, the queue activates an external process that handles the SMTP delivery, including retries, logging and all that. Overall system is quite resilient, scalable and performant.

Perhaps you're using the old, deprecated [xp_sendmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189505.aspx) based system?